# What are all possible HTML <head> tags?

Tags: html

What I knew (or found) that could be inside the HTML  tag:

- meta

  - charset
  - keywords
  - description
- title
- link

  - shortcut icon (icon for all browsers, shortcut to make it work with IE)
  - stylesheet
  - alternate (atom / RSS)
  - search
  - next / prev
  - made
  - [more rev/rel from Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/state-of-the-web/2005/linkrels)
- base href

**What other tags are valid and useful here?**
I don't really care about some obscure tags that were hot years ago or that only work in a few browsers. Instead I'm curious about not so known useful stuff that works in all browsers (or can be hacked into working with all browsers).

Comment: Did you even bother to read the spec?

Comment: since you tagged with html & html5 , which HTML version do you interest in ?

Comment: and user-friendly W3C wiki: http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_HTML_head_element

Comment: @BenM> Hmm no I didn't. And you are right, I should have. But... What is in the spec is currently supported by all major browsers? There is nothing in the spec that could today be considered as "totally useless" (ie hot x years ago but outdated/discouraged today?) And there are no useful head tags that are commonly used that are not in the spec? Usually the spec is authorative, but in the case of HTML I thought it was browser vendors that decide what works and that the W3C just tags behind? Or am I wrong here :)

Comment: Yes, but that's the kind of research that you should do on your own, not just ask a bunch of other people to do for you ;)

Comment: Yes ofcourse, let's all do this research ourselves because no one has ever done it before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the official docs [html 4.0.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html) and [html 5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-head-element) all the information you need is in there

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at processed [HTML specification at whatwg.org](http://developers.whatwg.org/).
Sections you are interested in are [Semantics: The head element](http://developers.whatwg.org/semantics.html#the-head-element) and [Metadata content](http://developers.whatwg.org/content-models.html#metadata-content).

Answer (score 0):

To Disable Cache in all browser

> ```
>   <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
>     <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
>     <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
>     <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
>     <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
> ```

To get indexing in search engine

> ```
>   <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
>     <meta name="googlebot" content="index, follow" />
> <meta name="robots" content="ALL" />
> ```

Decide the viewport for different devices to run your responsive css

> ```
>   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
> ```